# having trouble figuring one-line datetime calculation

Tags: javascript, python

im attempting to create a python script that log into local server via http request but it requires
local time but i think its encrypted but not sure
example: 2022.08.07.01.09.59 = 1659823799756
i took a look at the js code

```
 function getDuration(time) {
    let duration = 0;
    if (time.seconds) {
        duration += time.seconds * 1000;
    }
    if (time.minutes) {
        duration += time.minutes * 60 * 1000;
    }
    if (time.hours) {
        duration += time.hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }
    if (time.days) {
        duration += time.days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }
    return duration;
```

Comment: it's not encrypted, that's a timestamp https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: That is the epoch / unix timestamp. It is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 12:00:00 AM GMT. Yours seems to be in number of milliseconds since epoch. See [here](https://currentmillis.com/) for a converter. Does that answer your question? Or what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It is not encrypted, it is the epoch / unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 12:00:00 AM GMT. It can also be expressed in number of milliseconds (your case).

In Python you can get it with [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/time.html#time.time), to get the millis multiply it by 1000. If you need an integer value you have to round it, because `time.time()` returns a float.

```py
timeMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
```

See this link for the current Epoch in millis and for converters https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: cheers was scrathing my head about that one